# Segmentation Fault with const_iterator while using QT

Tags: c++, qt, vector, segmentation-fault

I'm developing a software similar to linkedin in C++ using Qt.
I have a problem when I try to save a user to the DB and in particular when I try to save his contacts.

The function the debugger says is wrong is the following

```
QString network::getAllContacts(const vector<user*>& d) const{
QString str="";
for(vector<user*>::const_iterator it=friends.begin();it!=friends.end(); ++it){
   for(vector<user*>::const_iterator it2=d.begin(); it2!=d.end(); ++it2){
      if(*it==*it2){
        if(str.size()!=0)
            str=str+","+QString::fromStdString((*it)->getLogin());
        else
            str=QString::fromStdString((*it)->getLogin());
      }
   }
}
return str;
}
```

It gave me a segmentation fault and shows me the line of the stl vector.h that says

```
{ return const_iterator(this->_M_impl._M_finish); }
```

Comment: Think hard about why you need a vector of pointers. Not only does it increase the memory management workload, but it is rare that this is the right choice. Also consider building the string as a std::string and converting to QString once at the end.

Answer (score 0):

STL iterators can't be a reason of segfault (just in case of inappropriate use) in your function. You are dereferencing some uninitialized pointer.

Setting a breakpoint in the beginning of this function will let you an ability to check "online" `d` and it's content (which are pointers! danger is right here) are correct. The same for `friends`.